# How can i store streaming video in resource folder in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, video-streaming, resourcebundle

If i go to the point then my problem is, i want to make a web view where it will load a video and when stream starts then i want to download/store that video data in the resource folder of the application.How can i do that?

Please somebody help me by any kinds of help.

BR

Emon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the run time you can't save a video to resource folder but you can save files in to 
NSDocuments and retrive them using NSFileManagers.Go through this link
    http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_on_the_iPhone

Try with this Code to save a file

```
 NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];                    
 NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/filename.MP4",documentsDirectory];
 NSData*   videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your Url"]];
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
 [filemanager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:videoData attributes:nil];
```

To retrive:

```
 NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];                    
 NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/filename.MP4",documentsDirectory];
    BOOL exists = [fm fileExistsAtPath:newDirectory isDirectory:&isDir];
    if (exists) {
     //Play Video with contents of file path. 

      }
```

Comment: can you give me an example because i am novice about these matter.